# How to use pre-aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I am building stats for online application. where I am logging every hits into MongoDB.

like

log =  {:user => 'Devid',:activity=>'Visited home page',:browser=>'chrome-5.3',:ip=>'10.11.35.211',:controller=>'home',:action=>'home_page',:created_at=>'2014-06-02 15:43:00'}

Mongo.insert(log)

pre-aggregations with controller-action combination

1. **log.daily.update**({_id=>'20140602-home-home_page',:metadata=>{:controller=>'home',:action=>'home_page',date=>ISODate("2014-06-02T15:34:23")}},{$inc:{daily.3=>1}},{:upsert=>true})

pre-aggregations with user combination

1. **log.daily.update**({_id=>'20140602-Devid',:metadata=>{:user_name=>'Devid',date=>ISODate("2014-06-02T15:34:23")}},{$inc:{daily.3=>1}},{:upsert=>true})

Similarly I am creating monthly and yearly aggregation. 
This gives for every hit to my webpage there are total 7 collections need to updated (1 need to create + 6 need to update if exist or create new collections).

My question is it a correct approach to built real time analytics ...??

Comment: The question comes off a little broad without giving a specific example and your use case. It is also a good idea to have **one** specific question that can clearly be answered. So consider the question you actually want to ask.

Comment: I was actually trying to help you by prompting you to edit your question into one clear question for a specific purpose. I don't think we need you to add comments that restate your two questions again. Explain your question. Pre-aggregate does not necessarily mean create a new collection for each range of data "week", "day" or "month". MongoDB will be comfortable with some level of polymorphism

Comment: Just a pointer -> https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/